# How do I create a regex that matches the last 2 specific digits in a 4 digit number?

Tags: regex

regex '[0-9][0-9]0[0]' matches both 7500 and 75000. I am looking for a regex that will only match 7500.

Desired result:
Match 7500
Does not Match 75000

Comment: Have you considered `==`?

Comment: Like `\b\d\d00\b` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match NN00 but not NN000 (N being 0-9), you need to match some "not" situations.  You can use a negated character class (`[^0-9]`) or the shortcut equivalent (`\d` matches a digit and `\D` matches a "not digit").  Depending on the string, you may also need to take into account what if the number appears at the beginning or end of the string.  This should be relatively robust for your needs:

```regex
(^|\D)\d\d00($|\D)
```